# Algorithms for Detecting the Completion of a Triangle in a Stream of Edges

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I need to efficiently determine in a complete weighted graph $G$ the sequence of triangles according to descending order of circumferences.

My idea would be to incrementally construct a new graph $H$, over the same vertex set as $G$, by adding the edges one by one according to descending order of length and report the triangles in the order they appear in the incremental construction of $H$.

That however leads to the following

> **Question:**
>
> how can the the appearance of a triangle upon adding an edge to a graph be detected efficiently in amortized time?

Please feel free to provide algorithms that are dedicated to special situations like distances between pairs of points in the Euclidean plane.

Comment: Detecting triangles in a graph is discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193228/how-to-find-a-triangle-inside-a-graph and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521126/determine-if-a-graph-contains-a-triangle and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705824/finding-cycle-of-3-nodes-or-triangles-in-a-graph and https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9972/finding-triangles-in-a-graph-other-approaches-besides-property-testing and probably other sites that come up on typing *detecting triangles in graphs* into Google.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know that the problem of detecting triangles in graphs is wellknown problem, but it doesn't solve the problem of enumerating them in a specific order. The motivation for requiring a specific order of enumeration is to be able to terminate the enumeration if for example one is only interested in the $k$ triangles with largest perimeter,or if one wants to safe the $O(n^3)$ space for collecting the data and then sorting it with an additional factor of $O(log(n)$